# Getting mail for a bounced email

Tags: php, email

I am sending email using `mail()` The problem is I am not getting an email to a specific email id if the recipient id does not exists, I have tried the following code.

```
$email="abcdt01est@gmail.com";
$usermsg="some message here";
$subject = 'Your Account Registration Confirmation';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";    
$headers .= "From: Our Team <team@test.com>" . "\r\n";              
$headers.="Return-Path:<my email id goes here>\r\n";
mail($email, $subject, $usermsg, $headers);
```

I have also tried with

```
mail("abcdt01est@gmail.com", "subject", "body of message", "From: team@test.com", "-f<my email id>");
```

Comment: So you are writing me those mails? Btw as far I remember you always need to use \r\n as line delimiter.

Comment: Explain clearly what you want..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch email bounce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874192/catch-email-bounce)

Comment: I want that a mail should go to my email id if it bounces, when I say bounces means if the recipient email id does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Mail function in PHP mail() only informs about E-Mail has been accepted by the outgoing server, and plays no role in checking E-Mail's actual delivery status.

You can check your mail log `/var/log/mail.log` if sendmail is configured properly.

Visit this http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9-PHP-PHP-mailer-to-compose-and-send-MIME-messages.html - MIME E-mail message sending: PHP mailer to compose and send MIME messages.